# Why does code doesn't work but starts to work when i debug it and thereafter

Tags: c++, mfc

I am sure this has happened to me in past as well, this behavior is quite weird.

I run my application which doesn't do a certain thing that it should do. I start to debug it and now without any code change, the application just works. Somehow the debugger wakes it up and 'put it on right path'? It continues to work after that.

In this particular instance, my app should have created a log file. I tested it on two computers and there was no log! I start to debug it (without any code change) and bang it does produce the log as it should.

What could be the mystery behind this?

My code if that matters is below. I write a log file to memory and here is when I create the actual file from it.

```
memFile.Write("End Log", 8 ); //mark end of log (its filled up prevoiusly)

int len = memFile.GetLength()+ 1;
BYTE *mBlock = memFile.Detach();
CFile file(_T("c:\\app\\log.txt"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeReadWrite );
file.Write( mBlock, len );
file.Flush();
file.Close();
```

The memory log file is created in different dll where it's defined (global in .cpp file).

```
 __declspec(dllexport) CMemFile memFile(1024*2);
```

In function calls, the following write to logfile.

```
    CStringA text;
    text.Format("DB Locked %d\r\n", GetCurrentThreadId() );
    memFile.Write(text, text.GetLength());
```

There are other literally same calls where I write to memory file.

Comment: This kind of thing is common if you have code with undefined behavior. The undefined behavior produces different results depending on how you run the code.

Comment: When code randomly work or randomly break, this is a very good sign of undefined behaviour. Without more code we can't help you more.

Comment: @Barmar in this undefined behavior gets built into executable since it didn't work on two computers? In this case, I don't see any signs of undefinedness, this code is under button click, the memory file is created in another file. I can't say for rest of application but as far as this log it's pretty clear. p.s I add this log as debug aid so it's only in two files.

Comment: We'd have to see a [mcve] to say anything more. Its not going to be easy to produce one.

Comment: In debug mode the system defaults variables to values. In release build this does not happen. So is it possible you have some undefined variables causing you a problem?

Comment: Undefined behaviour mean that when running the part of the executable corresponding to the code, the result of the execution is undefined. To be more precise, when a compiler try to compile code with undefined behaviour, it can generate code that can do anything: crash, erase your drive ... or it can simply not generate code

Comment: @PasserBy I added more code.

Comment: @zar read the link that PasserBy gave you ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). With the code that you gave, we can't help you.

Comment: @nefas the nature of problem itself is that it's not reproducible but the code really is what I posted.

Comment: How is `CFile`, `CMemFile` and `CStringA`  (and maybe `GetCurrentThread`) implemented ? From the info in your question, it look like you have a UB (or maybe uninitialized variable) but we can't help you more info (aka more code). Since I don't know much about development on windows I can't advise debugging tools (on linux I would have advised [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) and [clang UBsan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html)).

Comment: @nefas these three are all MFC constructs, not my code. I am using mfc library.

Comment: Does the folder `c:\app` exist on the other two computers? This is just what I'd expect if it doesn't.

Comment: You should NEVER EVER release memory that was allocated in one dll from another DLL.  I'm referring to the call to `memFile.Detach()`.  DLL's in one application space share memory, but not necessarily the same heap management - they could be written in different languages, or use different versions of the runtime library - you could have a debug/release runtime lib mismatch.. This can cause terrible issues down the road, that can be very difficult to solve.  This may also be the cause of your problem, since you are in UB territory.